# by comparing text in button array with string array unable to perform onclick in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

hi i am doing one app here when i click button  that time i need to disaply  a to z values  in one textview radomly.in textview each time i need to display one value only.so i using one string array i disply in text view  one value.and apply random fun also it working fine.then same page another place i need to disply some buttons like a,b,c....z.using anthoer string array i displyed those buttons.but the problem is when i click 'a' button means that time i need to compare button value to textview value, now in  first button 'a' is there that in textview also 'a' is there means i need to perform some action like button should be highlet.button and textview values not equles means  i need perform nothing. i treid using below code but i i am not getting.please can u any one suggest me...

```
   ButtonList .class:

        public class ButtonList extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
         String[] dishes = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};
      String[] dishes1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};
       String q = dishes1[rgenerator.nextInt(dishes1.length)];
            LinearLayout linear;
         TableLayout table;
       int dishQuantity =10;
       TextView text1;
          Button[] plus = new Button[dishQuantity];
          TableRow[] row = new TableRow[dishQuantity];
           String s1,s2;
          @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                linear = new LinearLayout(this);
              text1 =new TextView(this);
         text1.setText(q);
                s1=text1.getText().toString();
                  table = new TableLayout(this);
                         linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                      for (int i=0; i<dishQuantity; i++) {
                      row[i] = new TableRow(this);
               plus[i] = new Button(this); 
                         plus[i].setText(dishes[i]);
                          plus[i].setOnClickListener(this);
                      row[i].addView(plus[i]);
                           table.addView(row[i],60,30);
                        s2=plus[i].getText().toString();
                }
                        linear.addView(table);
                    linear.addView(text1); 
                          setContentView(linear);
          }
              public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if (s1.equals(s2)) {

                         ((Button) v).setEnabled(false);
                          }

                 }
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It nice if you get text from textview and button at on button's click,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
s2 = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
s1 = text1.getText().toString();

if (s1.equals(s2)) {
    ((Button) v).setEnabled(false);
    }
   }

 }
```

Comment: If its working then you can accept this answer as a correct by marking right symbol below voting button of left side of answer. This will help you and other user on SO.

Comment: the above example i need to apply random fun to dishes array also.i set    String q1 = dishes[rgenerator.nextInt(dishes.length)]; like this    plus[i].setText(q1);random fun working. but in all buttons coming same values.but i need all buttons with diff values